# Unit of the color in of the Diffuse Direct/Indirect passes in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, lighting, render-layers, render-passes

When I read a pixel's red value 1.0 from these passes, is the value I read radiance, radiosity or irradiance? Is it 1.0 W/m^2 or 1.0 W/(m^2sr)?

My understanding is that a sensor is sensitive to radiance. So can a pixel be considered as a pinhole camera sensor here?